# Word macro: when I duplicate a field, the duplicate is processed again. How do I skip the new field?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word-document with a series of cross-references. They currently refer to headings (see 'Safety'). I want to add the page number to each cross-reference (see 'Safety' on page 123).

I have a macro that finds the reference and pastes a duplicate of the cross-reference field (see 'Safety' on page Safety).
When I run this macro, the function Next objField finds the field I just inserted, and creates another duplicate (see 'Safety' on page Safety on page Safety). How can I make sure the new field I inserted is not being processed again?

```
For Each objFld In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If objFld.Type = wdFieldRef Then
            objFld.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.InsertAfter "' on page "
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
            Selection.Paste
            Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
            Set fld = Selection.Range.Fields(1)
            Set myrange = fld.Code
            With myrange.Find
             .ClearFormatting
             .Replacement.ClearFormatting
             .Text = "REF"
             .Replacement.Text = "PAGEREF"
             .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        End If
    Next objFld
```

Comment: You wanted a page number, which you will not get this way. Instead of duplicating your REF field, you should add a PAGEREF field. That also solves your second problem, as the macro will skip the new field.

Comment: I'm duplicating the field (so I get the cross-reference target), then doing a find/replace on the field code to get the PAGEREF.

Answer (score 1):

Your modifying a Collection (Fields) while traversing it. That can lead to strange behavior. So, copy the collection first:

```
Dim allFields As New Collection

For Each objfld In ActiveDocument.Fields
    allFields.Add objfld
Next

For Each objfld In allFields
[...]
```

The rest of the macro can remain the same.